# PHP loading data model without related models

Tags: php, yii, lazy-loading

After using Yii's CRUD generator (gii) and making some slight variations to the form generated, I am getting this error message:

```
[14-Jul-2012 05:12:58 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 40 bytes) in D:\apps\trulabel\framework\db\ar\CActiveRecord.php on line 1794
```

I believe I've narrowed down the issue to trying to pull in 22,000 rows from the item table.  Seems a little odd to me, as I thought it would handle that without difficulty.  Any suggestions on what might be going wrong, or a way around that?

Form:

```
<div class="form">
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'spec-definition-form',
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
)); ?>

    <p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>

    <?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>

        <div class="row">
                <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'labelTypeId'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'labelTypeId', CHtml::listData(LabelType::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'name')); ?>
                <?php echo $form->error($model,'labelTypeId'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'customer'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'customer', CHtml::listData(Tblarcustomer::model()->findAll(), 'Customer', 'Name')); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'customer'); ?>
    </div>

        <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'item'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'item', CHtml::listData(TblimItem::model()->findAll(), 'Item', 'Item')); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'item'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row buttons">
        <?php echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Save'); ?>
    </div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>

</div><!-- form -->
```

Comment: the line (of code) that you are using to load models will be helpful

Comment: hmm, I'm using standard CRUD forms generated by yii.  Of note: my items table has ~22,000 rows.

Comment: after your question's edit, you get this notification for actionCreate?

Comment: yes.  it can show the index page without error though

Comment: ok, that's helpful, can you just try all the actions, and confirm for which actions this error occurs? if its actionCreate, then i'm guessing it should come up for actionUpdate also.(you can check update from manage view, and click update icon, incase you don't know)

Comment: View, index, and admin all work, but update and create are both throwing this massive fit.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13876/discussion-between-bool-dev-and-johnz)

Comment: aha, so I accidentally pulled down new code, and overwrote what i thought I had.  the fault is with the loading of the item table as a dropdown.  That's the one pulling in 22,000 rows.  It's just not happy about that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Increase memory limit of php, it will solve your problem.

You can increase memory using :

```
ini_set('memory_limit','16M');
```

Comment: Nice suggestion! I forgot about setting the memory limit on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

By default yii runs in [debug mode](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.entry#debug-mode), which consumes a lot more memory from your php allocated memory in order to generate internal logs.

You can try to set it off from yii entry strip found in your app root (index.php) by commenting the line since the default value to "YII_DEBUG" is false:

```php
// remove the following lines when in production mode
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG',true);
```

Comment: Interesting, I thought it just dumped everything to the php error log, without doing too much.

Comment: well, yii maintains a very well nested debug trace which you see when you have an error but it's built anyway under the hood. Someone mentioned before that for fetching 1000 records it needed only 2M without debugging and 18M with debug enabled.